# How to check if the current snapshot key exists within different section of the same database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to check within an `addChildEventListener`  if the snapshot.getKey() exists within a different path in the same database.

I have 2 trees within the database. And whether they like activity is denoted by a true or false with the activity ID as the key

```
{
  "Activity": {
    "Do": {
      "-NTW-cLFvmgSqZ72EKuJ": {
        "name": "kayaking "
         },
      "-NTW-u8LJKsGd-wpcmir": {
        "name": "climbing "
      }
      
  },
  "Users": {
    "wkFbhmSH6lfPkkyy6OGke0be1ys2": {
      "gender": "Male",
      "preferences": {
        "Do": {
          "-NTW-cLFvmgSqZ72EKuJ": true}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to survey the user to ask if they like the activity or not but I only want to ask if they have not answered the question before.

To do this I have the following event listener that populates a question card for all the activities

```
DatabaseReference selectedActivityDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Activity").child("Do");
        selectedActivityDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot activitySnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                if (activitySnapshot.exists()){
                    currentActivityId = activitySnapshot.getKey();

                    cards item = new cards(activitySnapshot.getKey(),activitySnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    rowItems.add(item);
                    String key = activitySnapshot.getKey();
                    activityTpeArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

I want to check if `activitySnapshot.getKey()` is in users.child("Do").child("preferences") but I don't understand how to pass the `activitySnapshot.getKey()` into a listener checking in the "Users" tree of the database

I have tried a number of listeners and experimented with setting a global variable that would store the activity ID and check if that exists in a separate function but couldn't understand the intricacies of the listeners and how to pass in variables to them

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how is `selectedActivityDatabase` defined.

Comment: Hi Alex, changed the definition, in this example the database reference includes the information within the "Do" section of the Json but I want some way to check if the key generated by the code "-NTW-u8LJKsGd-wpcmir" is in the users preferences

Comment: I still cannot see how is `selectedActivityDatabase` defined.

Comment: Hi Alex, very new to this, not sure what you mean!

Comment: Is the Json in the first code box how it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how to pass the `activitySnapshot.getKey()` into a listener checking in the "Users" tree of the database.

You should create a new reference that points exactly to `Users/$uid/preferences/Do/$pushedId`, and attach a listener to it. In code, it should look like this:

```
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference doRef = db.child("Activity").child("Do");
    doRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot activitySnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            if (activitySnapshot.exists()){
                String currentActivityId = activitySnapshot.getKey();

                String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference ref = db.child("Users").child(uid).child("preferences").child("Do").child(currentActivityId);
                ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DataSnapshot result = task.getResult();
                            if (result.getValue() != null) {
                                boolean exists = result.getValue(Boolean.class);
                                if (exists) {
                                    Log.d("TAG", "The id exists.");
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("TAG", "The id doesn't exist.");
                                }
                            }}
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                        }
                    }
                });

                //rest of the code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey Seán. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi Alex, should it be doRef.addChildEventListener instead? I am not seeing the code enter this listener from what I can see

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not seeing the code enter this listener"? Have added a log and it isn't triggered? Does `onChildAdded` fire?

Comment: I added logs and onChildAdded does not fire, Android Studio shows that the Child event listener and doRef "are not used"

Comment: Using `doRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()...` does fire. If `task.isSuccesful` returns true but the for loop doesn't trigger from what I can see.

Comment: You're right, there is no need at all to use the for-loop. Sorry, my bad, I just removed it. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: From what I can see it works for all entries except the last one. If I have 5 nodes within the `Activity/Do` I see it correctly logging 4 times "the id exists" but on the 5th increment. the task is successful but the following error occurs `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference`

Comment: That happens because the last child key inside `Activity/Do` is not present inside the second node `Users/$uid/preferences/Do/$pushedId`. To overcome this situation, simply perform a null check as my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Hi Alex, I added an edit to yours where I changed the if null check as it was not working like that. `DataSnapshot result = task.getResult();
                                if (result.getValue() != null) {` I also used `doRef.addChildEventListener` rather than calling it at the end, is that acceptable?

Comment: Also the `if (result.getValue()!= null) {..}` is actually what checks if the tag exists. the exists result refers to the whether the user likes it or not!

Comment: Since it worked for you, I accepted the edit. And yes, it's another way of writing the code.